# SAP BI Edge Assistance

Tags: crystal-reports, business-intelligence, business-objects, crystal-reports-server

Up until a few weeks ago I have been using Crystal Reports 2008 and Crystal Server 2008. My expertise are in **Crystal Reports** and not Crystal Server/SAP BusinessObjects.

I was given some updated licenses to install and configure Crystal Reports 2013 and Crystal Server 2013. After looking into the software I saw a few nice additions from what we were currently using; mainly **Universes** and **Web Intelligence**.

After spending loads of time trying to get Web Intelligence added to my instance of Crystal Server; I was told that this only ships with SAP BI.

So... I installed `SAP BI Edge Edition` and result; Web Intelligence! But... I have seen the following issues:

1. When trying to open up the `Web Intelligence Web App` I got an error saying:

   > Cannot launch Java Report Panel, please make sure you have installed a Java virtual machine
2. I ensured that I updated JVM and finally got to the next stage. I then got an error in a popup saying

   > Your session timed out.  You need to close the Java Report Panel and log on again.
3. I decided to go back through the Configuration Wizard and had the error message

   > Unable to find servers in CMS <server_name:port> and cluster @<cluster_name> with kind fileserver and service FileStoreV2. All such servers could be down or disabled by the administrator (FWM 01014)

   and noticed that the `Input File Server` was disabled (but running) and I couldn't re-enable it.

I'm really losing my mind trying to figure all this out, and the SAP Documentation doesn't seem to be helping me much!

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Java error: I believe this happens if you don't have all necessary rights to the WebI application.  In CMC, go to Applications -> Web Intelligence, and review the rights that your user ID has.  I would start with Full Control to see if it works.

FRS error: in the FRS server properties page (in CMC), set the tracing level to at least Medium.  The stop and restart the server.  Assuming you're still unable to enable it, check the log file for any errors.

Comment: Thank you for responding :-) I got to the point of serious aggravation, and ended up reinstalling everything. I only have one problem now and that's the error when trying to open up the Web Intelligence app (`Your session timed out.  You need to close the Java Report Panel and log on again.`) 

I am logged in as the Administrator, so it shouldn't be due to permissions?

Comment: Also worth noting that I've also tried to run the BI Panel from the machine itself so it can't be a firewall issue.

Comment: Which version of the Java JRE do you have installed?

Comment: I have download and installed `Java SE Runtime Environment 8u92`

Comment: That is, unfortunately, a generic error with many possible causes.  Are you able to "View" reports successfully?

Comment: Outside of Web Intelligence? I can view reports in the module space, and in the Business Objects URL, yes.

Comment: Ok, so that at least means that the WebI services are running ok. Java 8 is supported in BI4, but it might be worth trying it with Java 7.  Can't guarantee it'll work, though.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to download Java 7? On their website it's discontinued with no option to download it.

Comment: Sorry ignore me - I can get it off their website! I'll get this done and report back.

Comment: Just tried with Java 7 and no, unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm.  Is there a "Details" button in the error box?  That might provide some more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other information at all. They are very informative with their error messages, aren't they :)